# How can data studio read a repeatable column as values of a single record?

Tags: sql, mongodb, google-bigquery, looker-studio

I'm moving a Mongo collection into BigQuery to do analysis and visualizations in Google Data Studio. I'm specifically trying to map all results of a `locations` collection, which has multiple records, one for each location. Each record stores the lat long as an array of 2 numbers.

In Data Studio, when i try to map the `locations.coordinates` value, it croaks, because it only pulls in the first value of the array. If instead of mapping it, I output the result as a table, I see 2 rows for each record, with the `_id` being the same and `locations.coordinates` being different between a row that has the latitude (`locations.coordinates[0]`) and another row for the longitude (`locations.coordinates[1]`).

I think I have to do this as a scheduled query in bigquery, that runs after every sync of data. But, I'm hoping there is a way to do this as a calculated field or a blended data set, in Google Data Studio.

[Data as it exists in mongo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpwhJ.png)

[Data as it exists in bigquery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ovjl.png)

[Data as it exists in data studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mnzd1.png)

- additional:
  [Big Query Record Types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjxY3.png)

Comment: Data Studio flattens all the repeated fields.

Comment: @allegorithm is Mosha's comment sufficient for you?

Comment: @MoshaPasumansky if you see the above screenshots, you'll see it doesn't "flatten" all the repeated fields. When you ask to show a table of the records, it splits them into two records.

Comment: This is what "flattening" means - it takes single record with repeated field, and flattens it into multiple records, duplicating the non repeating fields.

Comment: You could create a view in bigquery transforming the array entries into struct entries like `STRUCT(location.coordinates.value[offset(0)] AS lat, location.coordinates.value[offset(1)] AS long)`

Comment: @MartinWeitzmann you'll see the problem isn't the data type. I added a new image so you can see the record types of these values. the problem is i want to plot the records on a map.

Comment: @MoshaPasumansky ok, i understand. but how would i achieve what i'm trying to do? how can i take those values from the array and set them as unique key/values, so that I can view them in data studio (knowing in data studio, i can use a calculated field to concat them together, if they come through as two different columns). The answer from Martin doesn't make sense, because they are already set as a repeated struct, that then Data Studio flattens.

Answer (score 1):

You can address values in arrays directly and transform your data accordingly using struct etc.:

```sql
WITH t AS (
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST([
    STRUCT('a' AS company, STRUCT([-71.2, 42.0] as coordinates, 'Point' as type) AS location),
    ('b', ([-71.0, 42.2], 'Point')),
    ('c', ([-71.4, 42.4], 'Point'))
  ])
)

--show source structure of example data
--SELECT * FROM t

SELECT * except(location),
  STRUCT(
    location.coordinates[safe_offset(0)] as long,
    location.coordinates[safe_offset(1)] as lat,
    location.type
  ) as location
FROM t
```

[image: new result table]

There's `offset()` for 0-based access, `ordinal()` for 1-based access and with `safe_` you don't trigger errors in case the index in the array doesn't exist. If you need to know that values are missing, then you should use the version without `safe_`.

Anyway - this structure is flat by choosing specific values from the array. It should work with datastudio or any other visualization tool, there are no repeated rows anymore